# If $f'(x)\geq c$, show that $f(x)\geq f(0)+cx$ if $x\geq0$ and $f(x)\leq f(0)+cx$ if $x\leq0$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on Reals and that there is a positive number c such that...

If $f'(x)\geq c$ for all $x$, show that $f(x)\geq f(0)+cx$ if $x\geq0$ and $f(x)\leq f(0)+cx$ if $x\leq0$

I am pretty sure I need to use the MVT, but I got stuck, can you help?

Answer (score 4):

The claim is trivial if $x=0$, so assume $x\neq 0$.

---

The mean-value theorem applied
to $f$ restricted to $[0,x]$ implies the existence of a $y\in(0,x)$
such that 
$$
f^{\prime}(y)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}.
$$
Multiply both sides by $x$ and move some terms around to get
$$
f(x)=f(0)+f^{\prime}(y)x.
$$
Can you figure out the rest? **Hint**: break it up into two cases.

Comment: Yes! That was my mistake. Tried to do it all together. Thanks.